# How to create node.js error object in native addon?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I want to create an error object. But there is no `v8::Error::New()` How can I create an error object?

```
    v8::Handle< v8::Value > result = v8::Undefined();
    v8::Handle< v8::Value > error = v8::Undefined();

    if(m_errorMsg.empty())
    {
        // Not error
    }
    else
    {
        // HERE: Instead of a string I want an error object.
        error = v8::String::New( m_errorMsg.c_str() );
    }

    v8::Handle< v8::Value > argv[] = { error, result };

    m_callback->Call(v8::Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 2, argv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Node, you can just use the `ThrowException` method from the V8 API. It requires one parameter of type `Exception` which you can create with one of the static methods on the `Exception` class.

There are examples on how to do it [in this Node tutorial](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_function_arguments) but feel free to check out [my code on GitHub](https://github.com/Venemo/node-lmdb/blob/master/src/cursor.cpp#L49) too.

```
ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("This is an error, oh yes.")));
return Undefined();
```

NOTE: Don't forget to return with `Undefined()` after calling `ThrowException`. (Even `scope.close` is unnecessary in this case.)

Further reading:

- documentation of the `ThrowException` method:
  http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/namespacev8.html#a2469af0ac719d39f77f20cf68dd9200e
- documentation of the `Exception` class:
  http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1Exception.html

Answer (score 5):

actually the api was changed. now, you can throw an exception in this way

```
...
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
    String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Your error message")));
...
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know there isn't a `v8::Error` class but there's the `v8::Exception` that provides static member functions to construct different types of errors by supplying a `v8::String` argument.

Take a look at the [v8::Exception Class Reference](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Exception.html), that's probably what you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

Comment: the link is unavailable